# How to upload duplicate file in SharePoint 2013 document library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

How to upload duplicate files in SharePoint 2013 document library?  I know this is a very different requirement but we want in a SharePoint library multiple documents for the same name, How we achieve this?

Please suggest us the best options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short,** It's not logically an technically possible!

You can upload multiple files with the same name with a **different** file extension!

**Except that,**

- A new version will be added to the current file (`versioning enabled`).
- The current file will be overwritten with the new file (`No versioning enabled`).

---

**Workarounds**

- Using folders.

  - Can't save multiple files with the same name and extension in the same folder
  - **But** you can save files with the same name and extension in the same document library in different folders).
- Enable versioning.
- Using different file extensions.
- Automate unique identifier name for each document.